# What could be the reason Micro-Cap is showing very different current from LTspice for this circuit?

Tags: spice

I just try Micro-Cap SPICE simulator and trying to check it with LTspice.

I'm simulating [this](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91019/91019.pdf) MOSFET in LTspice with 10Hz 12V gate voltage and the gate current due to MOSFET capacitance peak to 200mA as in the following plot:

[image]

When I simulate the exact circuit in Micro-Cap the voltages are the same but the gate current is not how it is in LTspice not even close. Here is the setup in Micro-Cap:

[image]

As you see the bottom green plot shows the gate current which is like noise:

[image]

What could be the reason I'm getting very different gate current wave-forms?

Comment: I guess that in LTSpice you're using the **model** of the IRF530. Are you also using such a model in Micro-Cap or are you using some "generic" MOSFET? There can be a **huge** difference depending on the model. You can imagine that the behavior (and model) of a large MOSFET that can handle 100V, 10 A is quite different from the behavior of a MOSFET that sits somewhere deep inside a microcontroller on a chip with 1 million other transistors.

Comment: You probably also need to make the minimum time step smaller in microcap.

Comment: @Andyaka In Transient analysis window the Maximum time step was set to zero, I changed it to 1u now I can see peaking currents although not exactly the same but similar behaviour. So you were right it was about time step.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Im not using generic Im using exactly the same model.

Comment: First thing I see is you do not have identical circuits! Check the location of the gate resistors (R2,R3) and (Rg,R2). In the LTspice circuit Rg is useless as it is parallel to an ideal voltage source. (BTW, make sure if you want to show identical circuits, the reference designators are the same!)

Comment: Location of R2 and R3 doesnt change anything I tried already-.

Comment: use step time < 10% of expected rise time or use a faster clock for fewer steps and faster analysis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You probably also need to make the minimum time step smaller in microcap
```

> In Transient analysis window the Maximum time step was set to zero, I
>   changed it to 1u now I can see peaking currents although not exactly
>   the same but similar behaviour. So you were right it was about time
>   step.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuits above are not the same.  Look at the 10K gate pulldown resistor.. it is right on the gate for the microcap sim, but it is before the 47 ohm gate resistor on the LTSPICE.    Also it adds some confusion discussing the circuit because you didn't make the schematics have the same reference designators but that won't affect the results.